# Consulta mongoose

Tags: mongodb

Para poner en contexto

```
 const conditions = { 
    service: serviceID,
    address: { city: city, country: country} 
};

await serviceModel.find(conditions);
```

Address tiene otras propiedades a parte de city y country, pero quiero obtener los resultados que tengan ambos, sin importar que no tenga los demas. Cuando hago esa consulta no me devuelve nada porque address tiene otras propiedades tambien.

Answer (score 0):

quizas algo asi

```
serviceModel.find(
{service: "serviceID", "address.city":"city", "address.country": "country"}
)
```